# Angular - NgStyle fall back image

Tags: angular

**What I'm Using**

- Angular

**What I'm trying to do**

- When an image hasn't been returned from the server, use a placeholder image

**Issue**

- I'm not sure on the syntax. Any help here would be fantastic!
- Could there be a '?' check inside my ngStyle Background Image?

```html
<div class="image" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + (image.myImage | async)  + ')'}"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You syntax is correct but to achieve your desired behavior you do this:

```
<div *ngIf="image.myImage | async; let img; else loading" 
       class="image" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + img + ')'}">
</div>    

<ng-template #loading>
    <div class="image" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(/assets/placeholder.png)'}"></div>
</ng-template>
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6cajb8)**

Answer (score 1):

```
<div *ngIf="img" 
   class="image" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + img + ')'}">
 </div>
<div *ngIf="!img" 
   class="image" [ngStyle]="{'background-image':'url(http://via.placeholder.com/350x150)'}">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for also responding Asif. Much appreciated.